# Fragment is not attached to the FragmentManager

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I try to show my position on a googlemap that is displayed into a fragment. Fragment layout code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/window_background_color"
android:clickable="false">

<!-- Toolbar  -->

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:background="@color/primary_color"
    android:elevation="1dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:titleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
    app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="@string/toolbar"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp" />
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/test"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:background="#1c3049"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/help"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorAccent"
        android:text="@string/help" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spnCategory"
        android:layout_width="44dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="end" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mymess"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="95dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/test"
    android:orientation="vertical" />
```

Fragment is displayed from mainActivity :

```
FragmentTransaction mTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ActivityMap mFragment = new ActivityMap();
mTransaction.add(R.id.fragment, mFragment);
mTransaction.commit();
```

I call getUserPosition from:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mCurrentLocation = location;
    getUserPosition(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
}
```

and my getUserPosition code is:

```
  public void getUserPosition(double latitude, double longitude) {

    mCurrentLatitude = latitude;
    mCurrentLongitude = longitude;

    if (mIsMapVisible && isNetworkAvailable()) {
        TextView mytext = Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).findViewById(R.id.mymess));

        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getActivity(), Locale.ENGLISH);
        List<Address> addresses;
        try {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(mCurrentLatitude, mCurrentLongitude, 1);
            if ((addresses.size()>0)) {
                String str = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                if(str.contains(",")) {
                    mytext.setText(str.substring(0, str.indexOf(",")));
                } else {
                    mytext.setText(str);
                }
            } else {
                mytext.setText(R.string.no_adr);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            String temp = mCurrentLatitude + "," + mCurrentLongitude;
            mytext.setText(temp);
        }
    }

    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
            new LatLng(mCurrentLatitude, mCurrentLongitude),
            Utils.ARG_DEFAULT_MAP_ZOOM_LEVEL);

    mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);

}
```

Finally this is problem part:

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
            = (ConnectivityManager) getLayoutInflater().getContext().getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager != null ? connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() : null;
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

Here I get next error message:  E/UncaughtException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: onGetLayoutInflater() cannot be executed until the Fragment is attached to the FragmentManager.

First time when I run app work perfect. Second time I get error. And so on until my device ask if want to close application because he stop continues. I accept and next run work perfect. Then … problem spam again.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Fragments` have their own life cycle. When dealing with fragments, you always should consider they may be detached, hidden or their state was already saved.

Probably, the issue is happening because you are listen to location change events too soon. However, even if you change when you register your location listener, it is a good practice to get the `Context` (or `Activity`) in a safe way (because when detached, `Context`/`Actvity` will be null).

So, I recommend to:

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    boolean result = false;
    Context context = getContext();
    if(context != null) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager != null ? connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() : null;
        result = activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }
    return result;
}
```

`Fragment` has a `getContext()` method. So, you can replace `getLayoutInflater()` by `getContext()`